# Eclipse's Emulator (ArcGIS Android App)?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, arcgis

I am new to Eclipse. I am trying to learn it step by step. I am trying to create an ArcGIS app for Android using "**Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**". I followed this [tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/help/index.html#//011900000005000000), and noticed this sentence:

> "Be sure to have an Android device connected to the machine. We do not
>   support running in an Emulator."

My question is >>> How can I test my app? Is what have been mentioned is true?! I think that this tutorial is old because they are talking about old SDK version.

I thought about using the Eclipse's Emulator, and I tried it, but the app didn't work properly!! I am confused right now; because I don't know whether the problem is that:

1. ArcGIS apps don't work on Emulator!
2. My code is wrong!

My problem in details: [Hello World Map (ArcGIS) - Eclipse's Emulator doesn't run ArcGIS app properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927772/hello-world-map-arcgis-eclipses-emulator-doesnt-run-arcgis-app-properly)

Answer (score 1):

Since the ArcGIS page states that they do not support applications running on the emulator, please try to run it on an actual device. Also since it uses GPS, you may have to enable these settings on the emulator to make it work.

Also help us understand why it isn't working on the emulator? Is there a crash or a not responding? A Logcat may also be helpful for us to debug.

Comment: I would like to try it, but I don't have actual android device to test my app, and that is why I wanted to use the emulator for testing purpose. How can I enable emulator's setting to make it works?! --- I explained my problem in more details in this new question "Hello World Map (ArcGIS) - Eclipse's Emulator doesn't run ArcGIS app properly" >> Link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927772/hello-world-map-arcgis-eclipses-emulator-doesnt-run-arcgis-app-properly