# Hello World Map (ArcGIS) - Eclipse's Emulator doesn't run ArcGIS app properly

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, arcgis

I followed this [tutorial’s](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/help/index.html#//011900000005000000) steps. I named my project as “HelloWorld3” instead of “HelloWorld”. I followed all the steps carefully, and in my “HelloWorldActivity.java” I deleted what was already there (by default) and it was as the following:

```
package com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.esri.android.map.MapView;


public class HelloWorld3Activity extends Activity {

    MapView mMapView ;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mMapView = new MapView(this);

    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDestroy() { 
        super.onDestroy();
 }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.pause();
 }
    @Override   protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); 
        mMapView.unpause();
    }

}
```

I changed the previous code, and put this code instead:

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    MapView map = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        // Add dynamic layer to MapView
        map.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("" +
        "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"));

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        map.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        map.unpause();
    }
}
```

(I followed what was mentioned in the tutorial, but absolutely I named it as “HelloWorld3Activity”)

And then, my code became like this:

```
package com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.esri.android.map.MapView;


public class HelloWorld3Activity extends Activity {

    MapView map = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        // Add dynamic layer to MapView
        map.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("" +
        "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"));

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        map.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        map.unpause();
    }

}
```

However, there was a red underline under “ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer”!!

What is the problem?! I don’t know what to do!

[image]

I tried to solve the problem by clicking Ctrl+Shift+O  >> to update the missing imports (hoping that it will solve the problem.
The red underline disappeared, and my code became like this:

```
package com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.esri.android.map.MapView;
import com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer;


public class HelloWorld3Activity extends Activity {

    MapView map = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        // Add dynamic layer to MapView
        map.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("" +
        "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"));

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        map.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        map.unpause();
    }

}
```

Afterward, I tried to run it. I right-clicked my project “HelloWorld3”, and clicked on Run as > Android Application.
The emulator started, and I found my application’s icon. However, when I clicked on it, this screen (or window) appeared.

[image]

What is the problem?! 
Please help me!!

*** This is my previous related question "[Eclipse's Emulator (ArcGIS Android App)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926894/eclipses-emulator-arcgis-android-app)"

I am not sure, but I think that this is the Logcat:

```
10-17 12:38:19.820: I/dalvikvm(557): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-17 12:38:19.871: I/dalvikvm(557): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-17 12:38:19.911: D/dalvikvm(557): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld3/lib/libGLMapCore.so 0x412a6680
10-17 12:38:20.320: I/dalvikvm(557): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-17 12:38:20.371: I/dalvikvm(557): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-17 12:38:20.582: D/dalvikvm(557): Added shared lib /data/data/com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld3/lib/libGLMapCore.so 0x412a6680
10-17 12:38:20.601: W/ApplicationContext(557): Unable to create external cache directory
10-17 12:38:20.820: I/dalvikvm(557): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-17 12:38:20.851: I/dalvikvm(557): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-17 12:38:21.711: W/ApplicationContext(557): Unable to create external cache directory
10-17 12:38:22.021: D/libEGL(557): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
10-17 12:38:22.021: D/libEGL(557): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-17 12:38:22.101: W/dalvikvm(557): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
10-17 12:38:22.122: D/gralloc_goldfish(557): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-17 12:38:22.132: E/AndroidRuntime(557): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 75
10-17 12:38:22.132: E/AndroidRuntime(557): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
10-17 12:38:22.132: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface$a.chooseConfig(Unknown Source)
10-17 12:38:22.132: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1009)
10-17 12:38:22.132: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1362)
10-17 12:38:22.132: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
10-17 12:38:29.820: D/dalvikvm(557): GC_CONCURRENT freed 320K, 5% free 9217K/9607K, paused 6ms+8ms
10-17 12:38:31.741: I/Process(557): Sending signal. PID: 557 SIG: 9
10-17 12:38:38.980: I/dalvikvm(585): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-17 12:38:39.121: I/dalvikvm(585): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-17 12:38:39.371: D/dalvikvm(585): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld3/lib/libGLMapCore.so 0x4129e4c8
10-17 12:38:39.490: I/dalvikvm(585): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-17 12:38:39.532: I/dalvikvm(585): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-17 12:38:39.892: D/dalvikvm(585): Added shared lib /data/data/com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld3/lib/libGLMapCore.so 0x4129e4c8
10-17 12:38:39.900: W/ApplicationContext(585): Unable to create external cache directory
10-17 12:38:40.001: I/dalvikvm(585): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-17 12:38:40.033: I/dalvikvm(585): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-17 12:38:40.501: I/dalvikvm(585): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-17 12:38:40.530: W/ApplicationContext(585): Unable to create external cache directory
10-17 12:38:40.562: I/dalvikvm(585): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-17 12:38:40.780: D/libEGL(585): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
10-17 12:38:40.780: D/libEGL(585): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-17 12:38:40.911: D/gralloc_goldfish(585): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-17 12:38:40.921: W/dalvikvm(585): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
10-17 12:38:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(585): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 78
10-17 12:38:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(585): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
10-17 12:38:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface$a.chooseConfig(Unknown Source)
10-17 12:38:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1009)
10-17 12:38:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1362)
10-17 12:38:40.971: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
10-17 12:38:41.011: I/dalvikvm(585): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-17 12:38:41.041: I/dalvikvm(585): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-17 12:38:42.511: D/dalvikvm(585): GC_CONCURRENT freed 306K, 4% free 9231K/9607K, paused 20ms+123ms
10-17 12:38:54.530: I/Process(585): Sending signal. PID: 585 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post Logcat of the crash to investigate this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the ArcGIS API for Android was originally released, the emulator would not support it due to a lack OpenGL ES 2.0 support.  That has changed however.  Take a look at [this](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/05/02/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-v1-1-supports-android-emulator/).  You may need to make some changes to your target environment/install some additional packages.